# Who were the gurus of Brihaspati and Sukracharya?

Tags: guru, brihaspati, shukracharya

A Guru in Hinduism is of paramount importance in spiritual matters. So I want to know who were the gurus of Guru Brihaspati and Sukracharya? I heard that Shiva taught Shukra the art of reviving the dead. But I haven't come across any teacher for Brihaspati. Also, I don't think Shukra had only one teacher. Are there any names mentioned in the Puranas?

Comment: Sage Angirasa was Guru of Shukracharya . He and and Brihaspati studied under the same guru in childhood.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Could you please cite me the source?

Comment: Read this article - Under title Guru Shukracharya - Guru Shukracharya , i just came and finding the sources , may be we will find it somewhere.- http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Shukra

Comment: Also Lord Shiva gave Mritasanjeevani mantra to him. Do you only want the gurus who gave him the mantra or others who taught him.

Comment: "He went on to study the Vedas under the rishi Angirasa but he was disturbed by Angirasa's favouritism for his son Brihaspati. He then went to study under rishi Gautama. "- https://www.jatland.com/home/Shukra

Comment: Yes I am already aware of the part which Shiva played. Regarding the gurus, I wouldn't mind any category as long as it contains some names.

Comment: I too am aware of this story of Brihaspati and Shukra studying under Angira. But i have watched it on a TV serial. :P I can't cite anything here. And, this is actually the story of how Shukra was deprived from being the teacher of the gods which eventually Brihaspati became. @ArkaprabhaMajumdar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Devi Bhagavata Purana (Book 9; Chapter 4)](http://www.astrojyoti.com/devibhagavatam45-6.htm) talks about a particular Saraswati Mantra.

During different times the Mantra is said to have been imparted by various Gurus to their respective disciples.

> Besides all should worship the Devî Sarasvatî on the day of
>   commencement of education and every year on the S’ûkla Panchamî day of
>   the month of Mâgh. The eight-lettered Mantra, as mentioned in the
>   Vedas is the root Mantra of Sarasvatî. (Aim Klîm Sarasvatyai namah).
>   Or the Mantra to which each worshipper is initiated is his Mûlmantra
>   (not Mantra).
>
> Or uttering the Mantra “S’rîm Hrîm Sarasvatyai Svâhâ” one is to offer
>   everything to the Devî Sarasvatî.
>
> This Mantra is the Kalpa Vriksa (i. e., the tree which yields all
>   desires). Nârâyana, the ocean of mercy, gave in ancient times, this
>   very Mantra to Vâlmikî in the holy land Bhârata Varsa on the banks of
>   the Ganges; next **Bhrîgu gave this Mantra on the occasion of solar
>   eclipse to Maharsi Sukrâcharya on the Puskara Tîrtha; Mârîcha gave to
>   Brihaspati on a lunar eclipse;** Brahmâ gave to Bhrîgu in the Vadarikâ
>   Âs'rama; Jaratkarâ gave to Âstika on the shore of the Ksiroda ocean;
>   Bibhândaka gave this to the intelligent Risyasringa on the Sumeru
>   mountain, S'iva gave this to Kanâda and Gotama, Sûrya gave to
>   Yâjñavalkya and Kâtyâyana, Ananta Deva gave to Pânini, to the
>   intelligent Bhâradvâja and to S'âkatâyana in Bali's assembly in the
>   Pâtâla. If this Mantra be repeated four lakhs of times, all men attain
>   success. And when they become Siddhas with this Mantra, they become
>   powerful like Brihaspati. In past times, the Creator Brahmâ gave a
>   Kavacha named Vis'vajaya to Bhrîgu on the Gandhamâdana Mountain. I now
>   speak of that.

So, for those particular initiations, Maricha and Bhrigu were the Gurus of Brihaspati and Shukra respectively. And, there can be many more such Gurus for both of them.

(BTW I'm not sure who is Maricha here. Is [Marichi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marichi) mistyped as Maricha? One Maricha was of course a demon from Ramayana)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer on that context. But you're not aware of the other gurus of Brihaspati and Sukracharya, right?

Comment: And regarding Marichi/a, I think it is Marichi. A tamasic rakshasa, I personally and honestly think, is not eligible to initiate people like Brihaspati and Sukracharya.

Comment: In Vedic Dharma there are numerous Gurus. Because for each Yajna there is separate initiation (Diksha). Their fathers (Angira and Bhrigu) must as well be their Gurus too. Lord Shiva initiated Shukra into Mritasanjivani, so Lord Shiva was another Guru for Shukra. @ArkaprabhaMajumdar

Comment: Yes Lord Shiva is already mentioned in my question. I knew that part. Was just unaware about Brihaspati. Anyway thanks a lot for that :)